# After mastering px, em, rem and % font size I am confused by how to use Xpx/Yem

Tags: html, css, fonts

I saw this done on a page and the font size would scale perfectly on screen width change, I found they were doing it by going 14px/3em and so I tried, and it worked. But then ever since I have been trying it on other projects and it never works, it just sets the font-size to inherit and so makes the font uber small. Or default.

Could anyone explain this? It is not an issue with my code, or maybe it must be but the answer is probably reachable without any code examples?

Comment: What do you mean with 14px/3em? Setting 14px on the parent element and then 3em on the child? Remember em is relative to parent element, so it will just scale if the parent element also scales the font size depending on the size.

Comment: The only place where Xpx/Yem is valid is in a `font` shorthand property, where it means `font-size: Xpx; line-height: Yem;` Everywhere else, this would be a syntax error. Does that answer your question?